# The input taken in by my program is wrong(logic error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, logic

this is my code:

```
cart = ['S/n'," "*10, 'Items', " " * 15, "Quantity", " " * 8, "Unit Price", " " * 6, "Price"]
total_pricee = 0
pricee = 0
count=1
def invalid_input(Quantitiy):
    while Quantitiy > '5' or Quantitiy < '1':
        Quantitiy = input("Please key in a valid quantity(Between 1 to 4):")
        if Quantitiy < '5' and Quantitiy > '1':
            New_Quan=Quantitiy
            break
    while not Quantitiy.isdigit():
        Quantitiy = input('Invalid input.Please enter a valid input:')
        while Quantitiy.isdecimal() == False:
            break
def add_to_cart(name, Quantity, price):
    global total_pricee, pricee,count
    cart.append('\n')
    cart.append('{:<10s}'.format(str(count)+'.'))
    cart.append('{:^10s}'.format(name))
    cart.append('{:^30s}'.format(Quantity))
    cart.append('{:^10s}'.format('$' + '{:.2f}'.format(float(price))))
    pricee = '{:.2f}'.format(float(Quantity) * price)
    cart.append('{:^23s}'.format('$' + str(pricee)))
    total_pricee += float(pricee)
    count = count +1
while True:
    print('[1] Water')
    print('[2] rice')
    print('[3] ice')
    print('[0] View Cart')
    opt = input("Select option:")
    if opt > '3' or opt < '0':
        print("Select valid option!")
    if opt == '3':
        qunt = input("How many would you like?")
        invalid_input(qunt)
        nam3 = "Ice"
        add_to_cart(nam3, qunt, 2)
    if opt == '1':
        qunt2 = input("How many would you like?")
        invalid_input(qunt2)
        nam2 = "Water"
        add_to_cart(nam2, qunt2, 3)
    if opt == '2':
        qunt1 = input("How many would you like?")
        invalid_input(qunt1)
        nam1 = "Rice"
        add_to_cart(nam1, qunt1, 5)
    if opt == "0":
        print(*cart)
        print("Total price until now:", "$" + '{:.2f}'.format(total_pricee))
        print('Would you like to check out?')
        print('[1] Yes')
        print('[2] No')
        checkout=input("Please select an option:")
        if checkout=='1':
            print('You have bought',count,'items')
            print("Please pay""$" + '{:.2f}'.format(total_pricee))
            print('Thank you for shopping with us!')
            exit()
```

The problem I am facing is that when the user enters a quantity more than 5(refer to `invalid_input` function), the program asks it to give a quantity less than 6.However, when I apply the `add_to_cart`, it takes the original value the user put in(which is greater than 5).

```
[1] Water
[2] rice
[3] ice
[0] View Cart
Select option:3
How many would you like?6
Please key in a valid quantity(Between 1 to 4):5
[1] Water
[2] rice
[3] ice
[0] View Cart
Select option:0
S/n            Items                 Quantity          Unit Price        Price 
 1.            Ice                   6                  $2.00            $12.00
```

You see how it asked the user to key in a valid quantity(5) however the quantity taken by `add_to_cart`is the initial value(6).I want the quantity to display from the valid quantity.Help please!Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace the `>` to `>=` to avoid the error in your logic,

```
def invalid_input(Quantitiy):
    #look the Qunatity>=5
    while Quantitiy >= '5' or Quantitiy < '1':
        Quantitiy = input("Please key in a valid quantity(Between 1 to 4):")
        if Quantitiy < '5' and Quantitiy > '1':
            New_Quan=Quantitiy
            break
```

what happens if you give only `Qunatity> 5` and input `5` is that the condition becomes false.Because 5 is not greater than 5 itself.

Apart from this mistake when you were asking user to `Please key in a valid quantity(Between 1 to 4)` then you were not returning it back to your main module .Here is a modified version of your code,

```
#replaced cart with str1
str1="S/n\tItems\t  Quantity\tUnit Price\t\tPrice"
total_pricee = 0
pricee = 0
count=1
def invalid_input(Quantitiy):
    while Quantitiy >= '5' or Quantitiy < '1':
        Quantitiy = input("Please key in a valid quantity(Between 1 to 4):")
        if Quantitiy < '5' and Quantitiy > '1':
            New_Quan=Quantitiy

            #returned from here
            return Quantitiy

            break
    while not Quantitiy.isdigit():
        Quantitiy = input('Invalid input.Please enter a valid input:')
        while Quantitiy.isdecimal() == False:
            break
    #added the return here
    return Quantitiy

def add_to_cart(name, Quantity, price):
    global total_pricee, pricee,count,str1

    #replaced each cart statement with str1
    str1+="\n"
    str1+=str(count)+'.'+'\t'
    str1+=str(name)+'\t\t'
    str1+=str(Quantity)+'\t\t'
    str1+=str(price)+'\t\t'

    pricee = '{:.2f}'.format(float(Quantity) * price)
    pricee

    str1+=str(pricee)
    total_pricee += float(pricee)
    count = count +1
while True:
    print('[1] Water')
    print('[2] rice')
    print('[3] ice')
    print('[0] View Cart')
    opt = input("Select option:")
    if opt > '3' or opt < '0':
        print("Select valid option!")
    if opt == '3':
        qunt = input("How many would you like?")

        #getting the returned value to quant
        qunt =invalid_input(qunt)
        nam3 = "Ice"
        add_to_cart(nam3, qunt, 2)
    if opt == '1':
        qunt2 = input("How many would you like?")
        #getting the returned value to quant1
        qunt2=invalid_input(qunt2)
        nam2 = "Water"
        add_to_cart(nam2, qunt2, 3)
    if opt == '2':
        qunt1 = input("How many would you like?")

        #getting the returned value to quant1
        qunt1=invalid_input(qunt1)
        nam1 = "Rice"
        add_to_cart(nam1, qunt1, 5)
    if opt == "0":

        print(str1)
        print("Total price until now:", "$" + '{:.2f}'.format(total_pricee))
        print('Would you like to check out?')
        print('[1] Yes')
        print('[2] No')
        checkout=input("Please select an option:")
        if checkout=='1':
            print('You have bought',count,'items')
            print("Please pay""$" + '{:.2f}'.format(total_pricee))
            print('Thank you for shopping with us!')
            exit()
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: not really, the issue at hand is that the add_to_cart func does not take the output(in this case Quantity) as its input.Instead, it takes the initial input by the user(which is greater than 5) and carries out the operation.Thanks for the tip though

Comment: Ok i got it! i have edited my answer have a look at it

Comment: Hi, still shows error message:line 48, in <module>
    qunt1=invalid_input(qunt1)
NameError: name 'qunt1' is not defined

 and:line 23, in add_to_cart
    cart.append('{:^30s}'.format(Quantity))
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__

and
line 51, in <module>
    add_to_cart(nam1, qunt1, 5)

Comment: i have edited my answer  and the format error will occur as you are using formatting of string each time, just remove those formatting and work with simple code

Comment: sorry, i meant when quantity is double digit

Comment: are you new to python!

Comment: did you know how your code works or you have copied it from somewhere!

Comment: SFLR but when I tried your code, gave me this errors:

1:line 58, in <module>
    add_to_cart(nam1, qunt1, 5)

2:line 25, in add_to_cart
    cart.append('{:^30s}'.format(Quantity))
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__

Comment: @RohitKumar  i have done my last edit, which will be easy to understand for you as well as removing all errors.